# Playing multimedia content in sequence

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, mpmovieplayercontroller, nsoperation, nsnotifications

Hi I have an NSArray containing many 'multimedia action' as I like to call them, objects that encapsulate some multimedia content like movies and photos. I'd like to 'play' them in sequence waiting each one finished before calling the other.

**What is the best way to manage the duration of each operation before calling the next one?** (for  a photo imagine a UIAlertView that dismiss after some seconds delay, for a movie imagine a MPMoviePlayerController instead)

I'm already calling the method that scans the array with an NSOperation.

**IMPORTANT:** It appears that the MPMovieController does not play (the interface doesn't even appear) whether called inside a NSOperation. Has anyone else experienced this issue?

**UPDATE** Using `performSelectorOnMainThread:` makes the MPMoviePlayer work as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I've managed to find. I'm posting it in the case anyone is interested.

First I put all my 'multimedia actions' in a `NSOperationQueue` and i set the `maxConcurrentOperationCount` to 1, so I am certain that they will be run asynchronously from the main thread but only one at a time in a FIFO order (this is very important you you want that your content does not overlap on the screen).

Then for each action I activate it in a particular way depending on its class/kind. Let's suppose there are three kinds of actions:

1. UIAlertViews subclasses
2. MPMoviePlayerController-like
3. Background actions (actions that do not involve multimedia content to appear instantly on the current view

For the first two I use `NSNotifications` to manage the queue since I do not know when the content will stop playing or will be dismissed by the user (suppose by touch). So for each of those I:

- Pause the queue execution with `setSuspended:YES`
- Add an observer for the corrisponding NSNotification
- Play the content
- Post a notification when they finish playing
- Remove the observer and start the queue again with `setSuspended:NO`

For an UIAlertView the notification is posted with a `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` saying the amount of time it shall be displayed or after a double tap. For A MPMovieController instead it is launched automatically and is named `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification`. Both the UIAlertView and the MP kind shall be played on the main thread.

The third kind can be a set of instruction simply executed in the NSInvocationOperation put in the queue. So I can even create actions like 'wait' that suspend the queue eecution for some seconds